# How to get List of List instead of List of Array from a stream?

Tags: java, arrays, list, java-stream

I want to got a List of List instead of List of Array in the below code:

```
List<String[]> list = org.simpleflatmapper.csv.CsvParser.reader(in).stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How can we got `List<List<String>> list =` ... ?

Comment: Thanks both Eugene and mlecz! I just adjust my require is `List<ArrayList<String>>` instead of `List<String[]>`. Can you help me too!

Comment: I want to add some new data to the end of the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to map String[] to List

```
List<List<String>> list = org.simpleflatmapper.csv.CsvParser.reader(in).stream()
.map(Arrays::asList)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
org.simpleflatmapper.csv.CsvParser.reader(in).stream()
          .map(Arrays::asList)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```